# Angular 6 bootstrap 4 - navbar brand logo not change in scroll down

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular6

Im added my angular 6 project for he bootstrap 4 and Im created the navbar navbar is working good, but i have some conflict im tried to change when the scroll down change the navbar logo , but i don't know how to do that correctly on the angular.
anyone know how to fix that issue.

Thanks

[**Stack Blitz code here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijntkc)

header code part

```
<header class="main_menu home_menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" > <img src="https://www.seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/apple-logo-eps-logo-vector-400x400.png" style="width:50px;">   </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button></nav>
      </div></div></div></header>
```

Comment: So you want to change the logo after scrolling starts, right?

Comment: @Plochie yes , do you know the how to do that on the angular ?

Comment: For that to see you ll need to keep the navbar at top always. Im going through your stackbitz and I can see that there is no contents in the body. I ll add the placeholder and will get back to u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyskkc).

I am listening to `scroll` event and added binding to `img` tag to HTML.

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  logoPath = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?Text=oldLogo'

  ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scroll, true); //third parameter
  }

  scroll = () => {
    const scrollPos = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    // change '50' according to when you want to change the image
    if (scrollPos > 50) {
      console.log('New image');
      this.logoPath = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF00FF/808080?Text=newLogo';
    }
    else {
      console.log('Old Image');
      this.logoPath = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?Text=oldLogo';
    }

  };
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
          <a class="navbar-brand" > <img [src]="logoPath" ...
```

Comment: Hello dear, Thanks for your valuable time and guidance , it's really worked for me